# Selector to find closest DOM elements with attr greater than given

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have table created after AJAX which looks like that:

```
<tr data-level=2>
<tr data-level=3>
<tr data-level=4>
..etc.
<tr data-level=2>
<tr data-level=3>
<tr data-level=4>
..etc.
```

of course there may be many cells on any data-level.

I want to hide all rows greater than clicked level to row which level is smaller than clicked one. So - after I click data-level=4 I want to hide all elements with data-level > 4 till I get to row with data-level < 4.

Comment: I have updated answer see demo http://jsfiddle.net/pxW7h/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)</s>

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Example code*

```
$('tr[data-level]').on('click', function(){
    var level = $(this).data('level'); //Get level of clicked element
    $('tr[data-level]').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('level') > level;
    }).hide();
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qd2VT/)

Use

```
$('tr[data-level]').on('click', function () {
    var level = $(this).data('level'); //Get level of clicked element
    var arr = [];
    $(this).nextAll('tr[data-level]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('level') > level) {
            arr.push($(this));
        } else if ($(this).data('level') == level) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $.each(arr, function(){
        $(this).hide() 
    });
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxW7h/)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, `.data()` does it for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution

Edit: Sorry, the question wasn't clear, this solution hides all elements with greater value.

HTML

```
<table id="resultTable">
<tr data-level=2><td>2</td></tr>
<tr data-level=3><td>3</td></tr>
<tr data-level=4><td>4</td></tr>
<tr data-level=2><td>2</td></tr>
<tr data-level=3><td>3</td></tr>
<tr data-level=4><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("tr","#resultTable").on("click",function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var clickedValue = parseInt(el.attr("data-level"),10);
        hideLargerThan(clickedValue); 
    });    
    var hideLargerThan = function(value) {
        $("tr","#resultTable").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            var myValue = parseInt(el.attr("data-level"),10);
            if(myValue > value)
                el.hide();
        });
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKurcik/c8Q5Z/2/

you can derive from this code easily.

Comment: Thanks for fiddle, I have modified it for my example

Comment: well it hides all rows which number is greather than given data-level. And I want to hide only those ... closest, on from the whole page.

Comment: It's right in the question - "So - after I click data-level=4 I want to hide all elements with data-level > 4 till I get to row with data-level < 4." In Your solutions after I click on element 3 ALL rows on level 4 hides. I want only those which are on the way till they get to another level 2.

Comment: Updated my solution, it should give you at least a general idea. I'm sure somebody here will correct me.